# Estimate ratio of two expectations by sample means

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I have a question about the estimation of a ratio of two expectations. Suppose
$X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ are two random variables with $i=1,\cdots,N$. We seek to
estimate $\mathbb{E}X_{i}/\mathbb{E}Y_{i}$ by replacing $\mathbb{E}\left(\cdot\right)  $ with the sample mean. This will introduce a bias, as
$$
\mathbb{E}\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}X_{i}}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}Y_{i}}\neq
\frac{\mathbb{E}X_{i}}{\mathbb{E}Y_{i}}\text{.}%
$$
I was wondering if this can be solved, to some required (stochastic) order, by some analytical method (i.e. not jackknife or bootstrap).

Comment: Maybe this is related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables

Comment: @BGM, Thank you for the link but it's not really what I meant. The problem is that I have a ratio of expectations but I need to estimate the ratio unbiasedly; whereas the link is about how to compute the expectation of the ratio of 2 random variables. I have this wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_estimator) that is related to what I want but they show only the first- and second-order correction (Although the first-order correction is sufficient for part of my project.) whereas I need a general n-th order correction. But, thank you anyway!